# remove text from Redactor

Tags: redactor

Was just wondering how (or if) you can remove text from redactor:

(there might be a better way to deal with this all together - im option to suggestions)

the use case is I just want to have the video option (youtube links) for a specific field.

I have altered my config.json file for redactor:

```
 {
  "buttons": ["video"],
  "plugins": ["video"],
  "linkNewTab": true,
  "toolbarFixed": true
}
```

But this still allows text to added (so maybe this is not possible?):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add YouTube or Vimeo videos to your page, you'd be better off using a dedicated plugin such as [Embedded assets](https://plugins.craftcms.com/embeddedassets).

It allows you to treat videos as regular assets.